# Get values from associated table with Sequelize.js

Tags: sequelize.js

```
team table               match table
===========     ================================
tid= name       mid=   date =home_team=away_team
=============   ================================
01 = denver     01 =10.11.13 =   01    =   04
02 = minesota   02 =11.11.13 =   02    =   03
03 = orlando    03 =11.11.13 =   04    =   02
04 = portland   04 =12.11.13 =   03    =   01
```

I have a classical SQL JOIN problem - filled the match data and can't get the names of home and away teams that located in another table.

```
var Team = sequelize.define('Team', { ... });
var Match = sequelize.define('Match',{ .. });

Team.hasOne(Match, {foreignKey: 'home_team', as: 'Home'})
Team.hasOne(Match, {foreignKey: 'away_team', as: 'Away'});
```

As i understood from Docs after creating `as: 'Home` and `as: 'Away` i receive some 
getters and setters like `Match.getHome` but i'm confused. how can i used it

```
Match.find({where: {id: 1}}).success(function(match) {
    console.log(match);
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem lies in your association. You have only defined the assocation from team to match, but now you want to go the other way, from match to team. This means you have to do:

```
Match.belongsTo(Team, {foreignKey: 'home_team', as: 'Home'});
Match.belongsTo(Team, {foreignKey: 'away_team', as: 'Away'});
```

After that you can do

```
Match.find({where: {mid: 1}}).success(function(match) {
    match.getHome().success(function(home_team) {

    });
});
```

Or you can use eager loading:

```
Match.find({
    where: { mid: 1 }, 
    include: [
        { model: Team, as: 'Home'}
    ]
}).success(function(match) {
    // Here you can access the home team data in match.home
});
```

If you want both the home and away team at once:

```
Match.find({
    where: { mid: 1 }, 
    include: [
        { model: Team, as: 'Home'}
        { model: Team, as: 'Away'}
    ]
}).success(function(match) {
    // Here you can access the home team data in match.home and away team in match.away
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm very confused with all of these `.hasOne()` and `.belongsTo()`

Comment: You are not the only one, we often get questions about those. There is a TODO in the docs to make the types of assocations clearer, you can add your voice there if you want to https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-doc/issues/80 (I am a sequelize maintainer, that's why I know the associations so well :) )

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by that last comment? Could you perhaps update your question with the result you want to achieve?

Comment: perfect answer, I almost give up and this show related table, thank you